# how to cut a string in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I'm receiving a String like this:

```
"45,21,555,64,94,796,488,\n "   the \n means new line
```

is there a way to cut the string based on ","  and getting only the "number".

I could do it C but how can I search for a character in JavaScript.

thanks for any hint

Comment: you want something like `45\n21\n555` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var parts = "45,21,555,64,94,796,488,\n ".split(',').filter(function(val) {
    var num = parseInt(val, 10);

    return !isNaN(num) && toString.call(num) === '[object Number]';
});

// parts: ["45", "21", "555", "64", "94", "796", "488"]
```

This is taking your String and splitting it into an Array based on a delimiter (`','`) and then running it through a filter function to remove anything that does not evaluate to a valid Number.

See [`String.prototype.split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) and [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

If you actually want to then convert those values to Numbers, you could chain a [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) call:

```js
var parts = "45,21,555,64,94,796,488,\n ".split(',')
    .filter(function(val) {
        var num = parseInt(val, 10);

        return !isNaN(num) && toString.call(num) === '[object Number]';
    })
    .map(function(val) {
        return parseInt(val, 10);
    });

// parts: [45, 21, 555, 64, 94, 796, 488]
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, like this:

```
var myString = "45,21,555,64,94,796,488,\n ";
var splitStrings = string.split(",");
console.log(splitStrings); //Should log an array to the console, containing only your strings e.g. [45,21,555,64,94,796,488,\n]
```

This returns an array of strings, split by the character you passed in. You can read more on this method here: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp

After that, you can parse your array to remove anything you don't want like the new line character, or use a [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method to do it inline as detailed in another answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use `string.split(splitChar)` to split. Then you can use `.map` or `.filter` to convert items to number.

```js
var str = "45,21,555,64,94,796,488,\n ";
var arr = str.split(",");

document.write("Array: <pre>"+JSON.stringify(arr)+"</pre>");

var nums = arr.map(function(item){
    return parseInt(item);
});

document.write("Numbers: <pre>"+JSON.stringify(nums)+"</pre>");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are wanting just the numbers as an array you could do this.

```
var str = "45,21,555,64,94,796,488,\n "; 

var arr = str.split(","); //Make the string into an array
var len = arr.length; 
for(var i=0;i<len;i++)
{
    try
    {
        arr[i] = parseInt(arr[i]); // convert the numbers to ints
    }
    catch(e)
    {
        arr[i] = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: You should look for `Array.forEach`, `Array.map`, `Array.filter`

Comment: yes, your answer is cleaner than mine. I will remember those.

Answer (score 0):

As the fact that strings are just arrays, you can do it this way (a bit more comprehensive, in my opinion):

```
function noCommas(a)
{
    var b = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
    {
        if (a[i] != ',') //&& a[i]!= String.fromCharCode(10)) If you want no new lines too
        {
            b += a[i];
        } else 
        {
            //break; -> In case you only want the first value
        }
    }
    return parseInt(b); //To return the value as an integer
}
noCommas('1234,6789'); // returns 12346789
```

I missunderstood the question, so here's my fixed code:

```
function noCommas(a)
{
    var b = [];
    var tempNum = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
    {
        if (a[i] != ',' && i != a.length - 1)
        {
            tempNum += a[i];
        } else 
        {
            b.push(parseInt(tempNum))
            tempNum = '';
        }
    }
    return b;
}
```

now if you do `noCommas('123,345,324234')[2]` it would return `324234`.

Comment: I don't think this is what op wants. Also if you just want to remove commas, try regex: `/,/g` and use it in replace function

Comment: Why not? I think it does nearly what he wants.

Comment: He wants `1234` and `6789` as different values.  Your code is just removing `,` and not separating values